# How to make an error propagate out of EXEC and abort the rest of the script in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following trivial T-SQL:

```
EXEC('SELECT 1/0')
EXEC('SELECT ''a''')
```

It still executes the second EXEC statement. How do I abort the entire script upon the first failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside a try/catch:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC('SELECT 1/0')
    EXEC('SELECT ''a''')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Wow, I have never actually read about the semantics of BEGIN TRY/END CATCH, I just assumed that my knowledge of the exception semantics from regular programming languages (C#, C++, Java) just carries over to T-SQL. But this is different. Good to know. Thank you.